# Java swing Timetable manager

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am working on a timetable manager that has a feature similar to the new windows 8 functionality (movable blocks on the desktop).

A user can create a time-block, of lets say 2 hours with a name and then put it in the timetable by just dragging it in the appropriate place in the timetable, the blocks can interchange places when dragged into one another, a block can be dragged in between 2 other blocks etc.

I want to use Javax Swing to do that, and I want to distribute it under the standard JRE.

- What layout manager would be best to do it?
- Can we use several different layout managers under one window?
- Would it be best to apply absolute values layout?

Comment: I don't know how exactly should it look like, but I think you'll need XYLayout and create custom JComponents for the time-blocks. You'll also probably want to use JLayeredPane to put the components to. The calendar can probably be drawn directly to the pane before placing components.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify this you can use container (JPanel) with GridLayout (if all you blocks have the same size).

Define a block component (e.g. JPanel extension) with 2 states empty and filled but with permanent size.

Place the necessary amount of blocks (12) into the block component. On D&D just fill or empty the blocks.